# Why does MyObject.new.class === MyObject evaluate to false?

Tags: ruby, equality

I do the following, and it evaluates to `false`:

```
MyObject.new.class === MyObject
```

However,

```
MyObject.new.class == MyObject
```

evaluates to `true`. Can someone with a bit more Ruby background explain this to me, and if it's okay to use `==` for this purpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Ruby, `===` isn't a stricter version of `==`, as it is in some other languages.

The `===` method has several meanings:

#### Membership:

```
(1..10) === 5       # => true
```

#### Test whether the argument is an instance of the receiver:

```
p MyObject.new.class === MyObject.new  # true; it's the same as 
p MyObject.new.is_a? MyObject
```

#### Regex match:

```
/\w+/ === "Ruby"
```

#### Case statements:

```
year = 2011

case year
when 1901..2000
  puts 'Second millennium'
when 2001..2999
  puts 'Third millennium'
end
```

#### Other meanings, see `ri ===`

`MyObject.new.class == MyObject` is just a normal equality test (MyObject is a class object, and MyObject.new.class is the same class object)

Comment: And it’s used for the `case` statement.

Comment: The `case` statement? Really? Wow that explains a lot of odd behavior that I've observed over the years... Good to know!

Comment: @Josh Lee yeah, the case statement, I added an example to my answer, thanks